# How to find municipality and postal code that are in range from coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, azure-maps

Is there a way by using azure-maps or google-maps to get from longitude and latitude all postal codes and municipalityes that are in range of X kilometers?

I've yet checked the [Get Search Nearby](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchnearby) of azure, but it returns only points of interests and it is not possible to specify in the API a range in which the data should be get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Maps, getting all postal code/municipalities within a specified distance of a location or within an area is not currently available. However, this is something being investigated as a possible future service. Consider submitting this as a feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps

I don't believe Google Maps has any such service either.